# Apple Mach-O linker Error with exit code 1 with parse signup page

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

im trying to customise my log in forms it was working on the default set up and now i have inserted all the code in to customise it im getting this error on compile.
the code isn't showing any problems this is just on compile

here is the error output

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MySignUpViewController.fieldsBackground in:
    /Users/mikeaspinall/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeddingsAndMore-elgfqvgeaqmaksfrljnctjvknexm/Build/Intermediates/WeddingsAndMore.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WeddingsAndMore.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DMKWeddingHomeViewControler.o
    /Users/mikeaspinall/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeddingsAndMore-elgfqvgeaqmaksfrljnctjvknexm/Build/Intermediates/WeddingsAndMore.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WeddingsAndMore.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MySignUpViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MySignUpViewController in:
    /Users/mikeaspinall/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeddingsAndMore-elgfqvgeaqmaksfrljnctjvknexm/Build/Intermediates/WeddingsAndMore.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WeddingsAndMore.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DMKWeddingHomeViewControler.o
    /Users/mikeaspinall/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeddingsAndMore-elgfqvgeaqmaksfrljnctjvknexm/Build/Intermediates/WeddingsAndMore.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WeddingsAndMore.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MySignUpViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MySignUpViewController in:
    /Users/mikeaspinall/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeddingsAndMore-elgfqvgeaqmaksfrljnctjvknexm/Build/Intermediates/WeddingsAndMore.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WeddingsAndMore.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DMKWeddingHomeViewControler.o
    /Users/mikeaspinall/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WeddingsAndMore-elgfqvgeaqmaksfrljnctjvknexm/Build/Intermediates/WeddingsAndMore.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/WeddingsAndMore.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MySignUpViewController.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

my .m file

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Check if user is logged in
    if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
        // Instantiate our custom log in view controller
        DMKLoginViewController *logInViewController = [[DMKLoginViewController alloc] init];
        [logInViewController setDelegate:self];
        [logInViewController setFacebookPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"friends_about_me", nil]];
        [logInViewController setFields:PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword
         | PFLogInFieldsTwitter
         | PFLogInFieldsFacebook
         | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton
         | PFLogInFieldsDismissButton];

        // Instantiate our custom sign up view controller
        MySignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[MySignUpViewController alloc] init];
        [signUpViewController setDelegate:self];
        [signUpViewController setFields:PFSignUpFieldsDefault | PFSignUpFieldsAdditional];



        // Link the sign up view controller
        [logInViewController setSignUpController:signUpViewController];



        // Present log in view controller
        [self presentViewController:logInViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
```

More info on request if you need it

Comment: You posted "my .m file" but there are two implementation files mentioned in the link errors.  Have you examined both?

Comment: You have probably declared a variable in a header and are including this header in two source files (DMKWeddingHomeViewControler.m and MySignUpViewController), hence the duplicate symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may occur If you have imported the same file twice, check In your Compile SOurces or in your Project Navigator and see if you can  see MySignUpViewController twice if Yes then delete one of the references